# cakephp: submitting empty form give HTTP 404 page not found error

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, submit

How do I prevent my user from submitting an empty form? 
When I do that, I'm getting a HTTP 404 not found error in IE and a blank page in Firefox.
None of the validation errors are showing up.

I even tried putting an else stmt in the StudentsController's add function and that too is not firing. Nothing shows up for die(debug($this->Student->validationErrors)) either

I also have a beforeFilter in StudentsController. But I don't think that is causing any prob coz' i have already tried running this website by commenting the beforeFilter.

students_controller.php

```
 <?php
  class StudentsController extends AppController{
  var $name='Students';
  var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Ajax','Javascript');
  var $components=array('Security','RequestHandler');

 function beforeFilter()//executed before any controller action logic
{   
        //parent::beforeFilter();
    if(isset($this->Security) && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() && $this->action = 'getcities'){
        $this->Security->enabled = false;
        } 

}


  function add(){

    if (!empty($this->data)){

            //$student=$this->Student->saveAll($this->data,array('validate'=>'first'));
            //var_dump($student);
                  if ($this->Student->saveAll($this->data)){
                     $this->Session->setFlash('Your child\'s admission has been received. 
                     We will send you an email shortly.');
                     $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home'));
                  }else{
                     $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your admission could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));  
                  }

    } //for if (!empty....

    $states=$this->Student->MerryParent->State->find('list');
    $this->set('states',$states);

    $cities=array();    
}//end function
  }
  ?>
```

Following are my models with validation:
student.php

```
  <?php
   class Student extends AppModel{
var $name='Student';
var $belongsTo=array('MerryParent','MerryClass','State','City');

var $validate=array(
        'name'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('minLength',3),
                'required'=>true,
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Name is required!'
                ),
        'dob'=>array(
                'rule'=>'date',
                'required'=>true,
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Enter a valid birth date!'
                ),
        'class_id'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty', 
                'message'=>'Which class are you enquiring about?'
                )
        //'city_id'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Please select your city','required'=>true, 'allowEmpty'=>false)
        );
```

}
?>

merry_parent.php

```
  <?php
    class MerryParent extends AppModel{
var $name='MerryParent';
var $hasMany=array(
    'Student'=>array(
        'className'=>'Student',
        'foreignKey'=>'merry_parent_id'
                )
            );
var $belongsTo=array('State','City','MerryClass');

var $validate=array(
            'initial'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Please select your initial'
                ),
            'name'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('minLength',3),
                'required'=>true,
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Name is required!'
                ),
            'email'=>array(
                'rule'=>'email',
                'required'=>true, 
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Valid email address required!'
                ),
            'landline'=>array(
                   'rule'=>array('custom','/(0[0-9]{2,4}-[2-9][0-9]{5,7})/'), 
                   'required'=>false, 
                   'allowEmpty'=>true, 
                   'message'=>'Invalid phone number! phone number format: eg 020-22345678 OR 0544-7573758 OR 02345-874567'
                   ),
            'mobile'=>array(
                 'rule'=>array('custom','/([89]{1}[0-9]{9})/'), 
                 'required'=>true, 
                 'allowEmpty'=>false, 
                 'message'=>'Invalid mobile number! mobile number format: eg 9876543211'
                 ),
            'address'=>array(
                 'rule'=>array('alphaNumeric',array('minLength',1)),
                 'required'=>true, 
                 'allowEmpty'=>false, 
                 'message'=>'Please enter your address.'
                 ),
        'state_id'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                //'required'=>true,
                'message'=>'Please select your state'
                ),
            /*'city_id'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Please select your city','required'=>true, 'allowEmpty'=>false),
            'state_id'=>array('rule'=>'notEmpty','message'=>'Please select your state','required'=>true, 'allowEmpty'=>false),*/
            'postal_code'=>array(
                     'rule'=>array('numeric',6),
                     'required'=>true, 
                     'allowEmpty'=>false,
                     'message'=>'valid postal code required!'
                     )
            );//closing bracket for $validate array
   }
  ?>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if (!empty($this->data)){
>   if ($this->Student->saveAll($this->data)){
>      $this->Session->setFlash('Your child\'s admission has been received. We will send you an email shortly.');
>      $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home'));
>   }else{
>      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your admission could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));  
>   }
> }
> ```

Edit: What's the url when you get the 404? Because in default cake config, you'll only get missing controller or missing action, but not 404. You don't need to post the model, but do post the routes you have.

Comment: what do you mean by "data in the right structure"? By the way, none of the validation errors are firing.

Comment: Yes I do have validations for the models. I have included them in my code above now. Please take a look.

Comment: i'm sorry if i had misunderstood you. Which code am I supposed to copy?

Comment: if you are referring to the code in your cakephp book link above, i have already read them.

Comment: yes, i saw that. Sorry for my stupidity.....i didn't study your code well, it was looking similar to my code, so i thought it was just a copy of my code. I wasn't observant. I notice the change you have made. I will try it out now and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I copied your code but i'm still getting the same HTTP 404 page not found error in IE and blank add page in firefox. Please take a look at the changes i have made.